# Save routes on Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm making an Android app and I want to save and store the route you do as long as you walk with your location enabled. I'm using google maps apiV2 and i want to know if it is possible or not.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: @IntercoolerTurbo can you tell me where can I get the info to learn how?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/?hl=en

Comment: why is this question upvoted? There is no reason for this according to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible. All you have to do is to store the coords every time the method onLocationChanged is called.

Answer (score 0):

each time your [onlocationchanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onLocationChanged(android.location.Location)) listener is invoked you get a [location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) and from that you can get the latlng and other information . you can either save the entire Location object into an arraylist or just the latlng .

in both ways you can achieve what you want .